# Google Analytics API - Data for Line Chart

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, linechart

I want to create a Line Chart using data received by Google Analytics API.
It's no problem to plot a chart using Highcharts.js, but I'm searching for a solution for a performant query. The only idea i had is to make 30 Data requests for a 30 Day chart to get the pageviews on each day using the following query:

```
https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=$id&dimensions=$dimension&metrics=$metric&sort=$sort&start-date=$start&end-date=$end&max-results=$max_results&start-index=$start_index
```

Isn't there a way to receive this data in only one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't actually see the dimensions you're trying to query because you're using variables but you should just be able to use the `ga:date` dimension to get data split by day.

You can only download a maximum of 10,000 rows per query but you can use the `start-index` parameter to get the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can could set your $start and $end date variables to include 30 days. This should reduce your request from 30 to 1.

Comment: the result would be a number of all visiters during the 30 days. what i need is the number of visitors each day...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the dimension ga:day to the query. This will sort your data per day